# PHP header location - keeps refreshing - with exit() it won't show the page (blank page)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, url, http-headers

I'm using PHP header location to change the URL with a parameter from my MySQL database.

```
<?php
    include ('databaseconn.php');
    include ('search.php'); 
    header('Location: http://localhost:8888/docs/document.php?UniqueKey='.$row['UniqueKey']);
    exit();
?>
```

I have around 1000 rows in my database, each consisting of a UniqueKey like: **46fF5**. Every time I refresh my browser, it will call a **random** row from my database, including the UniqueKey that corresponds with that row.

**What I want**

I want to refresh the page, and that the link in my browser gets updated automatically. So I might have: localhost:8888/docs/document.php?UniqueKey=12dF2. If I refresh (F5) I want the NEW row to show its UniqueKey in the address bar.

**The problem**

The **exit();** function returns a blank page. If I remove it, the page will continue to loop through different unique keys, still resulting in a blank page (due to the 2 **include php files** that keeps refreshing for a new row).

I used an IF statement:

```
if(!isset($_GET['UniqueKey'])) { header loc code }
```

But then it only changes ONCE, and when I refresh the page, it will keep the first UniqueKey it found.

I don't know what to do. I tried "everything". Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Apparently I need to include the connection and search.php file, so here goes:

**databaseconn.php**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "mydatabase";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

**search.php**

A lot of code, but this is the part that matters (I presume):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM documents order by RAND()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: just to clairfy - this code (with `header()`) is also in your `document.php` file?

Comment: Well if you want help I would also post the `search.php` and the `databaseconn.php` as that where everything seemd to be going on

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry for the delay, it's updated!

Comment: @mitkosoft yes, the header is also in my document.php file

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez it's based on a click on a button, it will show another random document (so I guess manually?)

Comment: How about reseeding that RAND()?  Like, with a time.  Repeated calls to pseudorandom number generators without reseeding often will yield duplicate results.  Maybe this could be done by refreshing the query.

Comment: Is the first batch of code on document.php?  If it is, then why wouldn't it output a blank page?  There appears to be no output other than URL generation.

Comment: If you want this on a button click, do a separate php-script (called with ajax when user clicks the button) that just returns a random key. Then you only need to do a `location.href = '/docs/document.php?UniqueKey=' + theKey; ` in the ajax callback.

Comment: We need more code. Post the HTML code (button, form) to see how is document.php been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `SESSION` for that. The example below just show the idea, you can easily change the code for you needs:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if($_GET['rand'] == $_SESSION['rand'] || !$_GET['rand']){
        $rand = mt_rand(1,1111111);
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?rand=".$rand);
    }else{
        $_SESSION['rand'] = $_GET['rand'];
    }
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

After each refresh the `GET` parameter will be different as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Next is an example of how to refresh the page with different keys everytime, so you can compare it with your own (the random key is shown in the address bar after every refresh), as you said, the refresh must happen with the click of a button :

**zzz.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Current key :
<?php
// CHECK IF PAGE IS RETURNING FROM YYY.PHP.
if ( isset( $_GET[ "key" ] ) )
     echo $_GET[ "key" ];
else echo "No key";
?>
    <form action="yyy.php">
      <input type="submit" value="Refresh"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**yyy.php**

```
<?php
// REPLACE NEXT ARRAY WITH THE SQL QUERY.
$keys = array( "111","222","333","444","555","666","777","888","999" );
$index = rand( 0,count( $keys )-1 );
header( "Location: zzz.php?key=" . $keys[ $index ] );
?>
```

Copy previous codes in files with the given names ("zzz.php" and "yyy.php", sorry for the lack of creativity in the filenames), and open "zzz.php" in your browser.

We cannot see all your code, so it's hard to pinpoint exactly where is the problem.